# Prove that a set is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

I'm trying to prove that the set $B_a = \{ (x,y) : (|x|+1)^a \le y \le e^{x+y} \le y+10 \}$
is a) Lebesgue-measurable and b) its Lebesgue-measure is positive.

a) the set is the intersection of measurable sets like $ \{  (x,y) : g(x,y) \ge 0\}$ or $ \{ (x,y) :  g(x,y) \le 0\}$, where $g(x,y)$ is continuous, so is measurable.

b) can't procede on this one.
I sure know that $y\ge(|x|+1)^a \ge 1 $ and that $ln(y)-y \le x \le ln(y+10) - y $. But then?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first consider the inequality:
$$e^y \leq y + 10$$
With some elementary analysis, you can show that $y \mapsto e^y-y-10$ is strictly monotonous (increasing) over $\mathbb{R}_+$ and using a calculator you can see that the previous inequality is veryfied over $y \in [0, 2.5]$ (you can choose 2 or 2.3 I just took the two first figures from my calculator, the only zero of the function over $\mathbb{R}_+$ being approximately $\approx 2.527963$).
Okay...

Now you know that this other inequality is always verified over $\mathbb{R}$:
$$y \leq e^y$$
With a little bit of trivial analysis you can show that $\exists \epsilon_1 \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that the following property holds:
$$\forall y \in [0,2] \quad e^{\epsilon_1} \times e^y \leq y+10$$
(you can probably find a value for it, but I'm too lazy for that, sorry) meaning the following inequality holds for $y$ over $[0,2]$:
$$y \leq e^{\epsilon_1} \times e^y \leq y+10$$

And then, last step before we conclude, with again, a little bit of analysis, you can show that $\exists \epsilon_2 \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that
$$(1+\epsilon_2)^{|a|} \leq 1.5 $$
(for what ever value of $a$ you have) Now defining $\epsilon := \mathrm{Min}(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$; you can easily verify that:
$$\forall y \in [1.5,2] \quad (1+\epsilon)^{|a|} \leq y \leq e^{\epsilon} \times e^y \leq y+10$$
And then it follows that:
$$\forall x \in [0, \epsilon] \quad \forall y \in [1.5,2] \quad (1+|x|)^{|a|} \leq y \leq e^{x+y} \leq y+10$$
Since $\epsilon > 0$ the set $[0,\epsilon] \times [1.5,2]$ is of measure $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ i.e. has a strictly positive measure. But we have shown that this set is contained in your original set, so your original set has a measure of at least that (i.e. a positive measure too).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into it

Comment: Ok, I have to make a correction: $a$ here is $ \ge 0 $ according to the hypothesis.  Anyway, to find $x$ so that $ e^{x+y} \le y+10 $ holds, I proceded this way: $ e^x \le 1 \iff x \le 0 $, so that $ e^{x+y} \le (y+10)e^x \le y+10 $. So I now know that $ \exists y_1 \ge 0 $ and and $x_1 \le 0 $ so that $y_1 \le e^{x_1+y_1} \le y_1+10$.  What about the last inequalty.

Comment: I need an $x_2$ so that $(|x_2|+1)^a \le y_1 $, so $ |x_2| \le y_1^{1/a}-1 $. Keeping in mind that $ x2 \le 0$ I get that $-x_2 \le y_1^a-1$, so $x_2 \ge 1-y_1^{1/a} $. Seems right to me. The set should be $ [x_2,0] x [0,y_1] $

Comment: Don't worry, as long as $ \in \mathbb{R}$ you're fine.

Comment: I don't think you need toconstrain $e^x\leq 1$ but it seems to work okay... So good for you 

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment though. Can you explain the notation $[x_2,0]x[0,y_2]$ ? (I'm guessing $x \approx \times$ but it's to be sure...)

Comment: Also do you need the values or just existence?

Comment: Yes, I meant $\times$ , sorry. No, existence is sufficient. Thanks.